# How to get the details of error proved with TrackingId?

Tags: bing-ads-api

Provided with only the `TrackingId` of an error when accessing Bing Ads API, how can I know the details of the request and the error details?

I only can get this error:

```
(s:Server) Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information. TrackingId: x-x-x-x
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use the tracking ID to find the fault details. You should run debug tools such as Fiddler or tracing while calling one of the Bing Ads API operations. This would vary per language and environment e.g., see [.NET SDK Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/handle-service-errors-exceptions?view=bingads-13#net-troubleshooting-tracebehavior).